# Disable ng-Click while Dragging on Div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, draggable

I have enabled expand and collapse with my widget which has attached to a draggable directive.This works fine.

**ISSUE:**

The expand and collapse has been added in ng-click event, so when the user drags the widget and drop it ng-click also gets fired. I dont want ng-click getting fired when the user drags the widget.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div plumb-item  ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.left, 'top':widget.top, 'width':widget.width  }" data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable>
    <p ng-if="widget.divider">{{widget.chartConfig.title.text}}</p>
    <md-card ng-if="!widget.expanded && !widget.divider" ng-click="widget.expanded = !widget.expanded" ng-mouseover="hover = true" ng-mouseout="hover = false">
        <md-item layout="row">                                
            <div class="collapsed-row" layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
               <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                   <h3>
                <span>{{widget.chartConfig.title.text}}</span>
               </h3>
               </div>                      
            </div>                                 
        </md-item>
    </md-card>
    <md-card ng-if="widget.expanded && !widget.divider" ng-click="widget.expanded = !widget.expanded">
        <div layout="column">                                
            <md-card-content>   
                 <highchart id="{{widget.id}}" config="widget.chartConfig"  ></highchart>                         
            </md-card-content>
        </div>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

**JS:**

**Draggable.JS**

```
routerApp.directive('draggable', function() {
  return {
        // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
        restrict:'A',
        //The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM.
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("Let draggable item snap back to previous position");
          element.draggable({
                // let it go back to its original position

                revert:true
              });
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: you can add event.stopPropagation(),when the div dragging is done.

Comment: Inside the dragable directive?

Comment: yes,if you have any function/callback for dragging finish function

Comment: I tried that, does not make any difference

Comment: there is one function for draggable `element.draggable({ stop: function(event, ui) { event.stopPropagation();}` Have you tried this?

Comment: no i have not,you mean i need to include the above inside my draggable directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in you directive

```
routerApp.directive('draggable', function() {
  return {
        // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
        restrict:'A',
        //The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM.
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          console.log("Let draggable item snap back to previous position");
          element.draggable({

                 stop:function(event,ui) {
                          console.log("Check if its printing")
                          event.stopPropagation();
                                },

                            // let it go back to its original position

                revert:true
              });
            }
         };
     });
```

This stops the further propagation of events,so it may stop the undesired click

Comment: could you provide the complete code part including my directive?

Comment: I have added the directive code,check if it helps you

Comment: Warning: this appears to require jQueryUI's 'draggable' functionality to be included, yet jQuery is not listed in the question or answer.  Would help to augment the answer with this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I made a directive ([alClick](https://github.com/maaljam/alClick)) which is merely ng-click but cancels any click if the press duration is longer than 750ms by default. Therefore, no click or tap event will fire when dragging or swiping.

```
<div al-click="widget.expanded = !widget.expanded"></div>
```

Comment: I liked alClick until I found the warning I glossed over previously, `This directive removes/disables angular's ng-click. You will not be able to use al-click along with ng-click.`  It was unacceptable for my app (and most apps, I'd guess) to remove ng-click functionality.  I hope the author (@Mohammed A. Al Jama) of alClick can modify it so that it can co-exist with ng-click!  I'm sure there is a way, and it'd make his software product much better.